# TV episode/movie Alien ripoff with prisoner

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This is a show/TV movie I saw in the early 2000s, and it may have just been an episode of a larger show. For all I know, it may be famous. I only remember a few scenes and that it was quite similar to *Alien*.

The crew starts off doing their routine, until they get a call from a beacon and are instructed to retrieve it. When they get it into the ship, they find out it is not an alien but a prisoner that was in stasis in a coffin-like pod filled with a green liquid.

The prisoner starts picking them off, with one getting their neck sliced and another getting sucked out of a garbage chute and exploding. Another is killed with an axe. The last two crewmen, the black captain and female officer, are ready to kill the prisoner. At this point, the woman turns on the captain and shoots him, and the prisoner also dies. She gives a monologue about how she survived, and it is amoral and mind-screwy. Cue credits.

Comment: Was it of high quality, or was it a low-budget, crappy ripoff?

Comment: About the quality of an ok TV movie I think

Comment: See [our great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some recommendations to improve this. Great question!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly season 6 episode 14 of *The Outer Limits* title ["Abaddon"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667857/?ref_=ttep_ep14).

> In the late 23rd century, an outdated starship is on a ten-year reclamation project. The crew is in suspended animation and awakes to find a mysterious object floating in space. The pod contains the body of a rebel who was seemingly executed 150 years earlier for the slaughter of more than a million people. However, it turns out that he is still alive.

Black captain, female crew, prisoner, murders and *The Outer Limits* is usually somewhat mind screwy, your mileage may vary on amoral though.